# Passing Data using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I wrote a browser plugin using JQUERY. The plugin is basically a Bookmarklet and it displays a quote for my services on an external site. I want to pass this data back to my website on click of a button. I cannot use Cookies since they cannot be used cross sites.

Ideally I just want to pass all the innerHTML of the div I create on the external site.

Can you provide some pointers or something helpful to look at ? I dont find any meaningful help with Google as I understand that this issue is specific.

Thanks very much for your help !

Comment: Create and submit a form, for example to a hidden iFrame or load an image using a php file that returns an image

Comment: Thank you very much mplugjan ! I appreciate your help and feedback. I was able to post data from my bookmarklet to the remote host.